# Can we edit GoogleService-info.plist of an iOS/Android App project

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, info.plist, configuration-files

I already have an iOS app(example_bundle_identifier: **com.example.mobotechnology**) linked in the firebase project. Now I just want to change the bundle_identifier(example_bundle_identifier: **com.example.mobotechnology.org**) of the iOS app. So can we directly change the *BUNDLE_ID* of the existing *GoogleService-Info.plist* or we need to add/create new iOS app in firebase and replace with **new** *GoogleService-info.plist*?

Comment: some keys and parameter needs to be changed so better to when you set firebase account and then downloaded file put so it's best way to create new

Comment: @jazzbpn, you can change Bundle identifier in firebase then change value in GoogleService-info.plist. If you are creating new app on firebase then the best approach is to download new GoogleService-info.plist for the project. Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Okey that means creating new App on firebase and downloading new GoogleService-Info.plist is the best option. THANKS !!